# How do I enable location services for a specific website on Safari for OS X?

Tags: macos, safari, geolocation

In the past I've disabled Location Services for a specific site in Safari for OS X, but would now like to enable it, for that site only. How do I do that. None of the instructions I've found describe the current user interface for Safari (e.g., there is no ["Reset Safari" window](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204690) in 9.1.2).

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me in Safari 12.0.

Go to the specific site you want to change the setting for.

Now, from the Safari menu (next to the Apple menu), choose *Settings for This Website*.

A pop-over should appear, with a Location setting at the bottom.

[image: Example of Safari Settings for This Website, with Location setting selected]

Comment: Yeah, now it’s easy!